# If $X$ is non-negative and bounded, then $ \mathbb E[e^{-X}] \le \frac{1}{e\mathbb E X}$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, moment-generating-functions

I guess this result is true, so I'm trying to prove it. Could you have a check on my attempt?

> Let $X$ be a non-negative bounded random variable. Then
> $$
> \mathbb E[e^{-X}] \le \frac{1}{e\mathbb E X}.
> $$

*Proof:* The inequality holds if $\mathbb E X=0$. Now we assume $\mathbb E X>0$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$. Then
$$
\mathbb E[e^{-(X+\varepsilon)}] = \mathbb E \left [(X+\varepsilon)e^{-(X+\varepsilon)} \frac{1}{(X+\varepsilon)} \right] \le \frac{1}{e} \mathbb E \frac{1}{(X+\varepsilon)} \le \frac{1}{e} \frac{1}{\mathbb EX + \varepsilon}.
$$

The second inequality follows from $\max \{xe^{-x} \mid x \ge 0\} = e^{-1}$. The second one follows from Jensen inequality for the concave function $x \mapsto x^{-1}$. The result then follows by taking the limit $\varepsilon \to 0^+$.

Comment: Why is the first inequality? The second inequality is follows by Jensen and the first inequality is by the $\max_{x>0}xe^{-x}=1/e$?

Comment: @user1027216 you use multiply and divide by the same positive number.

Comment: Suppose that $U=(X+\varepsilon)e^{-(X+\varepsilon)}$ and $V=\frac{1}{X+\varepsilon}$ why $\mathbf{E}[U\cdot V]\leq \max U\cdot \mathbf{E}V$? Can you show that?

Comment: @user1027216 Because $UV \le V/e$, we get $\mathbb E[UV] \le \mathbb E[V/e]$. I thought this is quite obvious, no?

Comment: Well, in your post you asking by a check. I think the only way is know each part of our solution. It's the only way to understand our step. That is the way I evaluate my arguments myself, asking and answering questions even if they are elementary.

Comment: @user1027216 my previous comment did not mean to offend. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: @Akira The function $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ is not concave but on convex on the set of positive real number. The inequality you want to prove is not true in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result does not seem to be true: Take $X$ to be $0$ with probability $0.5$ and $1,000,000$ with probability $0.5$. Then $E[e^{-X}] \geq 0.5$ but $EX \geq 500,000$.

Comment: You are right. I should stop at $\mathbb E[e^{-X}] \le \frac{1}{e} \mathbb E \left (\frac{1}{X}\right)$.